# What is the difference between both code...Please explane

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('join', function (name) {


        people.id = socket.id;
        people.name = name;


        socket.emit('serveruser', people);
})
```

VS

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('join', function (name) {


        people.id = socket.id;
        people.name = name;


        io.emit('serveruser', people);
})
```

Comment: [1] you have to listen on `socket.on('serveruser', function() {...})` & [2] you have to listen on `io.on('serveruser', function() {...})`

Answer (score 1):

If I remember, the first case is to emmit to the connected user in the `join` channel the `serveruser` event.
The second case is to emit to all server users the event `serveruser`.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. **socket.emit** is used to send an event named *serveruser* to only the client which has just connected to your server. While **io.emit** is used to send the same event to all the connected clients. See [socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/)